# Can you use a class library if you don't reference all of it's dependencies?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, owin, class-library

Let me clarify:

I have built a class library to be used in several projects. As part of this DLL I want to add a few different custom providers for Owin Cookies by extending CookieAuthenticationProvider so I need to include a reference to Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies. This is safe because the newer projects that will use my library also use Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.

However some of the projects are older and dont use Owin etc... Will they blow up if I include the library for other use? Or will they only blow up if I try to use the provider (which I wouldn't since they cant use it).

I want to put some commonly used things in my library without having to reference every one of it's dependent DLL's to every project that uses them. I'm pretty sure what I'm doing is ok but I was hoping somone could tell me before I waste many hours going forward with this. Also if there is a better way I'm all ears.

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356819/c-sharp-getting-references-of-reference?rq=1?

Comment: Yes but that's slightly different. I just want to include things that expose references to 3rd party things in this one DLL. What I'm asking is will it always blow up if I use this in another app without referencing it's dependencies, or will it ONLY blow up if in the application I try to access something in from this library that uses one of those dependancies I haven't added references to.

Comment: afaik assemblies define their dependencies and Visual Studio resolves these dependencies. If a dll of that dependency tree is not found VS will complain at compile time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The rules:

- All types which are visible to a given assembly must be declared in assemblies referenced by that assembly.
  As long as your class library does not actually *expose* in its public API the types found in the `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies` assembly, then other assemblies can safely compile with your DLL without referencing that assembly.
- A referenced assembly need not be present at runtime, except when code in that assembly is actually needed, i.e. some other code attempts to call that code.
  In *general*, this means that as long as other assemblies which are referencing your assembly and which don't reference `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies` also don't call any code in your assembly that would then in turn attempt to call code in `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies`, that assembly need not be present at runtime.

The tricky part on that second point is that what constitutes "calling code in `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies`" is not always clear. Typically, as long as you don't access the types in the assembly at all, .NET won't try to execute any code in that assembly. But it's not hard to accidently access the types even when they are not necessarily needed (e.g. in initializers, `static` or otherwise, code that checks for interface implementations, etc.).

If you really want your clients to be able to use your DLL, which references `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies`, without necessarily needing that DLL to be present at runtime, you will need to be very careful to ensure you've fully supported that scenario. It is possible to do, but it's also not hard to make a mistake.

*(I have to admit, I'm surprised that this useful question hasn't already been addressed on Stack Overflow. Seems like it would have come up before by now. But I was unable to find a duplicate, hence the answer above. If anyone is aware of a duplicate I've overlooked, I welcome any suitable notice of that.)*